# JQuery - cannot read property 'Editor' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I'm trying several WYSIWYG HTML5/JQuery editors. However, with both Bootstrap WISWYG and Summernote, I get 'cannot read property 'fn' of undefined' or 'cannot read property 'Editor' of undefined. I'm just using the standard files out there on GitHub. Anyone familiar with these errors using JQuery plugins?

**EDIT**

I'm now trying [Bootstrap WISWYG](http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-wiswyg-rich-text-editor)

Within my body I have

```
<div id="editor">Editor</div>
```

In my js, I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#editor').wysihtml5();
});
```

However, the error I get is:
Cannot read property 'Editor' of undefined (line 157)

Line 157:

```
var editor = new wysi.Editor(this.el[0], options);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8125/

**EDIT 2**

I forgot to include one JS file. However, after including it I get a new error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
```

The lines of code that the error refers to:

```
if (isString) {
  element = wysihtml5.dom.getAsDom(elementOrHtml, context);
} else {
  element = elementOrHtml;
}

while (element.firstChild) <<<Error
```

Comment: Try uploading your mock to jsfiddle or anywhere we can see it (not)running

Comment: *"cannot read property 'fn' of undefined"* most probably means that you haven't included jQuery in your page

Comment: Included the JSFiddle link in the post.

Comment: "Within my body I have

<div id="editor">Editor</div>"

Within your body? Does it hurt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you are using a `DIV` element instead of a `textarea` there are also dependencies missing. Checking the Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 page it says:

> Dependencies:
>
> - bootstrap-wysihtml5.js
> - bootstrap-wysihtml5.css
> - wysihtml5
> - Twitter Bootstrap

Then your document should look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
    <title>HTML5 Editor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Of course place sources in your own server, do not leech bandwidth -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/lib/js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jhollingworth.github.io/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jhollingworth.github.io/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css">
</header>
<body>
   <textarea class="editor"></textarea>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.editor').wysihtml5();
       });
   </script>
</body>
```

For further reference, please check: [Wysihtml5 #Usage](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/#usage)

Comment: I was missing the 3rd file, thanks! However, I get a new error that I included in the OP.

Comment: Hi, that happens because you are trying to add an editor to a `DIV` instead of a `<textarea></textarea>` element. Have you replaced the `<div id="editor"></div>` by `<textarea id="editor"></textarea>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
"cannot read property 'fn' of undefined"
```

usually means that the script does not have script being loaded into DOM.  You might are missing jQuery file?  I have often noticed that it is becoming a practice for jQuery scripts to be loaded right in the bottom of HTML, right before

```
</body>
```

But, it always works so well if I loaded only one Jquery file in header meanwhile the rest of other jquery plugin scripts loaded in the bottom of the html file.

Comment: I included a JQuery file in my file. The other scripts are being loading after the JQuery file.

Comment: I tried different orders. However, it seems that JQuery first, WYSIHTML5 second is the right order, since it doesn't say that wysihtml5() is not a function.